# Como o arquivo recebe os $_POST?

Tags: php, formulário

Bom dia pessoal, tenho que fazer uma manutenção em um formulário antigo e estou tentando entender como ele funciona...

Abaixo o arquivo form_proposta.php

```
<?
$msg = "Mais informações de imóvel enviado em " . date("d/m/Y") . ", os dados seguem abaixo: " . chr(13) . chr(10) . chr(10); //nessa linha, estará impresso em que data e hora foi enviado o formulário
$msg .= "Código : " .$codigo . chr(13) . chr(10);
$msg .= "Nome : " . $nome . chr(13) . chr(10); //aqui o campo nome 
$msg .= "E-mail  : " . $email . chr(13) . chr(10); //campo email
$msg .= "Endereço : " . $endereco . chr(13) . chr(10); //campo endereco
$msg .= "Telefone : " . $telefone . chr(13) . chr(10); //campo telefone
$msg .= "Mensagem : " . $mensagem . chr(13) . chr(10); //campo mensagem

$Remetente = $email; //aqui, colocamos que o email digitado seja quem enviou o formulário, pode ser substituido por "Contato do Site", assim, sairá sempre que quem  enviou o email, seja Contato do Site

$para = $email_from;

mail($para, "Proposta do site",$msg,"From: $Remetente\n");
?>
```

Abaixo segue o html da página

```
<form action="../exec/form_proposta.php" method="post" >
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" >
                        <tr align="left">
                            <td align="left">C&oacute;digo:&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <h1>{$imo_cod}</h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="left">
                            <td >Nome:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="left"> <input type="text" name="nome" style="width:400px;" class="campo"> </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr align="left">
                            <td>E-mail:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="left"> <input type="text" name="email" style="width:400px;" class="campo">  </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr align="left">
                            <td>Telefone:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="left"> <input type="text" name="telefone" style="width:400px;" class="campo"> </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr align="left">
                            <td>Endere&ccedil;o:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="left"> <input type="text" name="endereco" style="width:400px;" class="campo"> </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr align="left">
                            <td align="left">Mensagem:&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
                            <td align="left"> <textarea rows="6" name="mensagem" style="width:400px;" class="campo"></textarea> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" align="center"><br>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" style="width:100px;" class="campo" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                  
                            <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Limpar" style="width:100px;" class="campo" />   
                            <input type="hidden" name="codigo" value="{$imo_cod}" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="email_from" value="{$alt_email}" />  
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

Estou olhando esses códigos a um bom tempo e não entendo como esse negocio pode funcionar, o arquivo php não é incluido em nem um outro arquivo é acionado diretamente pelo formulário...

Em nenhum momento encontrei o local onde são pegos os $_POST e atribuídos as $variaveis...

Basicamente a minha conclusão até o momento é que ele funciona com mágica kkk
Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender como esse negócio funciona?

Comment: Você está aver o ficheiro php errado. Dê uma olhada a `../exec/form_proposta.php`

Comment: @Sergio não estou(infelizmente). o código php que coloquei na pergunta é o código desse arquivo

Comment: Não tem nenhum `extract()` perdido por ai? ou `register_globals` habilitado(php.ini)?

Comment: @perdeu `register_globals` está habilitado... `extract()` eu não encontrei nenhum

Comment: Desabilita agora essa bagaça! qualquer parâmetro passado numa url vira uma variável quando o `register_globals` está `on`.

Comment: @perdeu dei uma lida a respeito e é mesmo muito perigoso deixar isso ativo, o problema é que os sites antigos da empresa foram baseado nessa "coisa"... não posso desativar, mas pelo menos sei como está funcionando agora...

Comment: @RodrigoBorth qual o site da sua empresa mesmo? hahaha

Comment: @gmsantos é terra.com.br xD aushaushau

Comment: Acho que eu poderia aproveitar o exemplo e mudar a pergunta para "Quais o problemas e perigos mais comuns ao se habilita `register_globals`?" o que acham?

Comment: @RodrigoBorth acho uma boa ideia. Isso ou uma pergunta nova.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quando o [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.globals.php) está habilitado as querystrings passada em um url virão variáveis ou seja isso é uma porta escancarada para invasores injetarem códigos maliciosos. Na no php5.3 esse recurso foi descontinuado e no php5.4 removido.

Para resolver o problema será preciso atribuir manualmente as variáveis o valor de $_POST/$_GET e aos poucos ir migrando isso por que esse recurso é `evil level 9999³³³³³³³`.

com register globals on

```
$msg = "Código : " .$codigo . chr(13) . chr(10);
```

Como deve ficar

```
$msg = "Código : " . $_POST['codigo'] . chr(13) . chr(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra coisa que pode ser feita para não precisar mexer muito é utilizar o `extract()`.

Como você tem um form com os nomes dos campos corretamente definidos, você poderia utilizar `extract($_POST)`, resolvendo o problema;

Comment: é interessante ao negativar de uma explicação construtiva assim todos evoluímos

Comment: Bom acrescentar na resposta os riscos do `extract`, como sobreescrever variáveis de maneira indesejada, pois a flag _default_ é `EXTR_OVERWRITE`, que "atropela" tudo que já havia sido definido anteriormente. Pra falar bem a verdade, na minha humilde opinião, o `extract` só deve ser utilizado em situações extremamente controladas (e de preferência substituido por coisa melhor o mais rápido possível).

Comment: Concordo @Bacco