# Como pegar valor $_POST automaticamente?

Tags: php, html

Tenho esse form.

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="nome">
</form>
```

Teria como pegar o valor do `$_POST` no php automaticamente?

Preciso pegar os dados de um formulário onde não sei os nomes dos campos ou a quantidade.

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="nome">
   <input type="text" name="outro-campo">
   <input type="text" name="outro-campo2">
</form>
```

Ao invés de fazer

```
echo $_POST['nome'];
echo $_POST['outro-campo'];
echo $_POST['outro-campo2'];
```

Preciso de algo automático mas não sei como.

Comment: Por favor, poderia explicar melhor o que precisa? sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente.

Comment: Se houvesse seria como trocar 6 por meia duzia.

Comment: Como assim automaticamente? Magicamente fosse para uma outra página e já caia para (exemplo) uma variável chamada $nome?

Comment: Não deu para entender muito bem o que vc deseja ... me parece que o mais próximo seria o uso da função `extract()` ela converte um array em variáveis (os nomes são as chaves) porém se não for bem tratado ou não tiver muito controle da situação abre brechas de segurança parecidas com o [register globals](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33411/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi bem sua pergunta ficaria desta forma:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="nome">
</form>
```

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'nome') {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Acho que o que pretende é tentar criar variáveis normais com base nos valores que o `$_POST` tem.

**Embora isso não seja boa ideia pois pode abrir brechas de segurança**, pode faze-lo da seguinte maneira:

```
foreach ( $_POST as $chave => $valor ) { $$chave = $valor; }
```

Que cria uma variável com o nome que vem no `$_POST` e para cada valor que lá vem.
Depois é só utilizar como se fossem variáveis normais:

```
echo ($nome);
```

Alternativamente, a criação dos nomes pode ser feita à custa da função `extract` como o Anderson Carlos Woss e rray sugeriram. Para isso basta apenas chamar a função:

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "prefixo");
```

O parâmetro `EXTR_PREFIX_SAME` indica que caso exista colisão de nomes deva ser criado um prefixo, com o texto relativo ao 3º parâmetro, que no exemplo acima foi `"prefixo"`,

[Exemplo a funcionar](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/050bed94ebd328467c420eba65e2edeb3dfc5af7)

Comment: Você pode utilizar a função `extract` que tem exatamente este objetivo. Mas não vejo motivos de se fazer isso tanto quanto o `foreach` sobre `$_POST`. Abrem brechas de segurança na aplicação se não bem tratadas, assim como comentado pelo rray na pergunta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim concordo plenamente, não é de todo boa ideia fazer isso, tal como já tinha dito logo no inicio da resposta, mas respondendo exatamente ao que ele perguntou, seria uma forma de o fazer. Se é que percebi a pergunta corretamente!

Comment: Negativei pois não tem a ver com variáveis variáveis.. O que se pede é iterar o array automaticamente sem saber quais os campos (índices) que existem nesse array. 
O uso do extract() e variáveis variáveis foge do contexto.

Comment: @DanielOmine Não foi o que eu percebi da pergunta, mas vou esperar que o autor do post se pronuncie sobre o que realmente estava a procura, porque de facto não estava muito clara.

Answer (score 0):

Era algo desse tipo que eu queria

```
print_r( $_POST);

foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
{
    echo $field;
}
```

Comment: quase isso, como vc pode ver ele retornar um array e nesse código ele pegar o index do $_POST voltando a minha pergunta eu queria saber se tinha algum atributo do php que fizesse isso.