# XAMPP 5.6.16, erro apache com globlas on

Tags: http, xampp

Instalei o Xampp 5.6.14, mudei a clausula para *on* (`register_globals=on`) no php.ini e agora o apache não inicia, da erro de aplicação.

Já fiz alterações das portas http para 8000 no httpd.conf e para 4430 no http-ssl.conf. O Skype está desligado e o netstat não demonstra uso das portas.

> 15:43:59  [Apache]    Status change detected: running 15:44:04  [Apache]
>     Status change detected: stopped 15:44:04  [Apache]  Error: Apache
>   shutdown unexpectedly. 15:44:04  [Apache]     This may be due to a
>   blocked port, missing dependencies,  15:44:04  [Apache]   improper
>   privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 15:44:04 
>   [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 15:44:04 
>   [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 15:44:04  [Apache]
>     If you need more help, copy and post this 15:44:04  [Apache]    entire
>   log window on the forums

Comment: Acho que isso [resolve o problema](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33410/91) ou pelo menos explica. Warning: danger ahead!

Answer (score 1):

Essa funcionalidade foi removida do php na versão 5.4 conforme o manual http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php.

O jeito é usar um pouco de regex para substituir certos trechos de código.

Comment: Usar register_global é um tiro no pé

Comment: @WallaceMaxters um tiro de bazuca xD